# Buying limitless (less restricted) Twitter API account

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm writing an app which works with the network of followers/followings for a specific user, and frequently I reach rate limit and I have to wait some time to be able to request again which is annoying. Is there any way to bypass this limit ? e.g. paying for an account to twitter, etc.

Comment: No as far as I know, you can buy Tweets from Gnip, but no followers etc.
User's graph is a valuable asset, so understandably they have to protect it somehow.

Comment: You can try to get certified by Twitter, [take a look](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/official-partner-program). Of course it should be quite difficult a "partner", but they have several levels of certification (and it's unlikely they give you *full* access anyway).